# How can I post a message from a customer/patron using the Salesforce LiveAgent REST API

Tags: salesforce, chat

I"m trying to figure out a way to work with the Salesforce live agent chat REST API but can't seem to find a way to post messages programmatically that would be from the agent.

For example: this endpoint

/salesforceliveagent.com/chat/rest/Chasitor/ChatMessage

only seems to post messages from the customer and not the agent?  Does salesforce have an open API that would allow posting messages from an agent?  This way I could potentially use a 3rd party platform for the agent to respond in and not salesforce?

I asked chatgpt and it told me to format the body like this.

```
{ "text": "Hello, how can I help you?",
```

"senderType": "Agent",
"senderName": "John Doe"
}

but this doesn't seem to update who the message is from at all.  It still sends it as the patron.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Salesforce documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.live_agent_rest.meta/live_agent_rest/live_agent_rest_Messages.htm) on that API:

> **Messages**
>
> Returns all messages that were sent between agents and chat visitors during a chat session.

The [ChatMessage object docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.live_agent_rest.meta/live_agent_rest/live_agent_rest_ChatMessage_response.htm) indicates that you can view the agent's response. Note this `ChatMessage` is different than the endpoint you mentioned. From their [example ChatMessage response docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.live_agent_rest.meta/live_agent_rest/live_agent_rest_response_bodies.htm#ChatMessage), the `text` is the message from the agent:

```json
{
    name: "Andy L."
    text: "Hello, how can I help you?"
}
```

Comment: thanks for the information but passing in the userid does't appear to impact the message at all.  It still is listed as being sent from the patron and not the agent.

Comment: @JamesD are you hitting the right endpoint? The one you mention in the description (`/salesforceliveagent.com/chat/rest/Chasitor/ChatMessage`) doesn't match the one from the docs (`/chat/rest/System/Messages`). I'd recommend reading through their documentation flow rather than using ChatGPT